# Null pointer (create() called for the missing output array) in create, file /home/m/OpenCV/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp, line 1461

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error, ubuntu-16.04, opencv3.0

I am trying to run an example of `Drawing labeled connected components` in O'reilly's book, but I get followings error message at run-time(I built the source without problems):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat img, img_edge, labels, img_color, stats;
// load image or show help if no image was provided
    if( argc != 2|| (img = cv::imread( argv[1], 0)).empty())
    {
        cout << "\nExample 8_3 Drawing Connected componnents\n" << "Call is:\n" <<argv[0] <<" image\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cv::threshold(img, img_edge, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::imshow("Image after threshold", img_edge);
    int i, nccomps = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats (
                         img_edge, labels,
                         stats, cv::noArray()
                     );
    cout << "Total Connected Components Detected: " << nccomps << endl;
    vector<cv::Vec3b> colors(nccomps+1);
    colors[0] = cv::Vec3b(0,0,0); // background pixels remain black.
    for( i = 1; i <= nccomps; i++ )
    {
        colors[i] = cv::Vec3b(rand()%256, rand()%256, rand()%256);
        if( stats.at<int>(i-1, cv::CC_STAT_AREA) < 100 )
            colors[i] = cv::Vec3b(0,0,0); // small regions are painted with black too.
    }
    img_color = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for( int y = 0; y < img_color.rows; y++ )
        for( int x = 0; x < img_color.cols; x++ )
        {
            int label = labels.at<int>(y, x);
            CV_Assert(0 <= label && label <= nccomps);
            img_color.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x) = colors[label];
        }
    cv::imshow("Labeled map", img_color);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

> OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Null pointer (create() called for the missing
>   output array) in create, file
>   /home/m/OpenCV/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp, line 1461 terminate
>   called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'   what(): 
>   OpenCV(3.4.1) /home/m/OpenCV/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp:1461:
>   error: (-27) create() called for the missing output array in function
>   create

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a debugger shows that this exception appears during the call to connectedComponentsWithStats(). The description of the error infers this as having something empty / null that shouldn't be that way.

OpenCV's [current docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f) show that the fourth argument, centroids, should be a 
CV_64F matrix with 2 columns and "centroids" number of rows. This matrix is probably initialized by the function itself, as long as it exists.

Thus, all you need is to create this matrix and provide it as expected by the function:

```
cv::Mat centroids;
int i, nccomps = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats (img_edge, labels, stats, centroids);
```

Your problem lies in using OpenCV 3.4.1 (latest) which has changed in syntax compared to the book you're using; this is a common problem to any open source library. I suggest you keep the current OpenCV docs at hand to make sure the code from the book still works, or downgrade to an older version.

Comment: Thank you Dany, But may i ask if you know what is `CC_STAT_AREA` in this line of code `if( stats.at<int>(i-1, cv::CC_STAT_AREA) < 100 )`  , and will be replaced by what in execution of code?

Comment: The total area (in pixels) of the connected component.
You can always check these things in the official docs, it has a search box for these things.
 (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ggac7099124c0390051c6970a987e7dc5c5a49573cd2ef1510fd96052d94feaac901)